# Azure Repos Extension in VS code commands not showing in commands

Tags: vscode-extensions, azure-repos

VS-Code version: February 2023 (version 1.76)

Azure Repos: Last Release July 10, 2023 (version 0.34.0)

I cannot see any commands from the installed extension in the Command Palette.

Any idea what might be causing this issue?